# Many short tasks on the gui

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, .net-4.0, backgroundworker

When I must do many short tasks, that are cooperating with GUI, should I use another `BackgroundWorker` for each task, or some other solution?

**EDIT**

I mean update every cell in datagridview (200 rows x 50 columns) every 5 second. Every cell stores image.

Comment: An example or two of the tasks that you have in mind would help a lot.

Comment: How "short" are we talking about? If you don't want the UI to freeze while your tasks are running, obviously you should use another thread. BackgroundWorker makes it easy to run your tasks in another thread and lets you know once the task is done and provides progress information.

Answer (score 2):

When I'm dealing with many small tasks, I tend to find that the [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) is a nice way of dealing with them. You can dispatch a delegate on a background thread like so:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(MyThreadProc));
```

You can also pass an object to the thread as it's state, consider a delegate that takes an object as a parameter. You could call this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(MyThreadProc), state);
```

Where state is some object that your thread knows how to deal with.

**Edit**: A `ThreadPool` approach should work just fine for your scenario. Just make sure that any code that changes your GUI will have to be invoked on the GUI thread, or you'll get some cross-thread exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

`BackgroundWorker` would be better suited to long running tasks, you want something like [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx). Here's a very crude example:

`QueueUserWorkItem` allows you to specify a worker method and pass in an object for that method to work on.

`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(DoWork), object);`

Then you would have your `DoWork` method where all the magic happens:

```
public void DoWork(object sender)
{
     object s = (object)sender;

     this.Invoke(new ThreadDone(ReportProgress), result);
}
```

Notice the call to `this.Invoke(new TaskDone(ReportProgress));` This safely calls code running on the main thread to update your UI with processed data from `DoWork`. This is done via a private delegate:

```
private delegate void ThreadDone(object yourObject);
```

Which would call:

```
private void ReportProgress(object yourObject)
{
       //update UI
}
```

You could also use this for checking when the task is complete by keeping track of an `Interlocked` counter object e.g.

```
foreach (string s in strings)
{
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(DoWork), s);
      Interlocked.Increment(ref workItems);
}
```

And then decrementing the `workItems` when a single thread completes and make a simple check for when `workItems == 0`

```
Interlocked.Decrement(ref workItems);

if (workItems == 0)
{
       this.Invoke(new TaskDone(WorkComplete));
}
```

Hope this helps.